# How to understand/expand r formula with matrix term on RHS

Tags: r, matrix, julia, formula

I have been doing piecewise mixed-effects growth curve regression in `lme4` using the `knots()` function posted at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/13361/fitting-piecewise-linear-curves-with-lmer to create knots and then calling `lmer` like this:

```
> df$knot<-knots(df$time,seq(1.5,3.5,.5)

> lmer(outcome ~ predictor*knot + (1+knot|id), data=df)
```

This works fine. `str(df$knot)` shows that it's a matrix:

```
num [1:1492895, 1:5] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
 ..$ : NULL
 ..$ : chr [1:5] "1.5" "2" "2.5" "3" ...
```

For speed, I'd like to fit these models using Julia (via JuliaCall) instead, but Julia doesn't grok a matrix RHS like R does.

So, my question: how does R `lm`/`lmer` understand a matrix on the RHS of a formula, and can I "expand" the matrix into regular vector columns in the data frame instead so Julia won't complain?

I tried:

```
> df$knot1<-df$knot[,1]

> ...

> df$knot5<-df$knot[,5]
```

and then using the formula

```
outcome ~ predictor*(knot1+knot2+knot3+knot4+knot5) + (1+knot1+knot2+knot3+knot4+knot5|id)
```

Is that right? What does R do with the RHS matrix predictor?

Comment: If you remove knot from the random effects I think it will run pretty fast with lmer.  `lmer(outcome ~ predictor*knot + (1|id), data=df)` .  See `vignette("lmerperf")` and additionally follow the tips there.

Comment: That's true, but then I wouldn't be fitting a growth model. (Or at least not the kind I'm trying to, with random slopes)

Comment: You would still have random intercepts and knots would still be used in the fixed effects but at any rate the point is that with this change the model should run quite a bit faster.

Comment: Thanks. I'd still like to understand what R's doing so I can try to do it "manually".

Comment: If `fm` is the result of running `lmer` then `model.matrix(fm)` and `model.matrix(fm, "random")` will give you the model matrices.

Answer (score 0):

Based on running test models with smaller data sets, it does appear that expanding the matrix into five dummy variables does work as expected, with R and Julia producing the same results (but with Julia running in 6 minutes and lme4 in about an hour for the same random intercept and slope model on a 5% subset of my data).

Comment: Suggest you run the reduced model and the full model and on the 5% subset see if there is any worthwihle difference.